# Different custom View controller for iOS splitViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I have a splitview controller containing master and detailview controller. But now i need to display different custom view controller based on the selection in the masterviewcontroller (a tableview). How can i achieve this?

Comment: i tried two methods. 1. Adding different views in the detailed viewcontroller based on the mastertable view selection. I think it is not the correct method, also there is some problem with the orientation. ie portion of the view is clipped

Comment: Why do you think populating a custom view controller's view upon selection of Master view table's row is incorrect??

Comment: Here i need different programming purpose for each row. So i thought , using  single viewcontroller with different view will make the implementation file complex. Do you think it is normal?

Comment: Its perfectly alright. To avoid if condition check to populate the custom view controller you may better go for switch statement

Comment: i done in that way, now portion of view is getting clipped. Will try to fix that. thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear! If you need any help, feel free. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in master view controller.
Take the decision of creating custom view based on indexpath value.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UISplitViewController *splitController = self.splitViewController;
     NSMutableArray *arr = [splitController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

     CustomViewController *customVC = [[CustomViewController alloc]init];
     [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:customVC];
     [customVC release];

     splitController.viewControllers = arr;
}
```

Comment: i tried that also , now the problem is after selecting one row the detailed view controller is displayed but the left navigation button is automatically disappearing. if i rotate the device and rotate again to portrait the button will come back